# magento get Applied RuleIds in flatrate page

Tags: magento-1.7

Can anybody tell me how to get `applied rule ids` in `Flatrate.php` page (shipping/Model/Carrier)? Actually I want get Rule_id which is applied for the order (table:salesrule) in Flatrate.php. In Flatrate.php page there is a function `public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)` if I print the `$request` it shows a long result which is impossible for me to find out the rule id but I m sure it consists all the information of applied ruleids. So if anyone knows Please help me.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, had the same issue. Your code works fine in 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 5):

You chould be able to get the current checkout/quote data thru:

```
$quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

Then from the quote object you can get the getAppliedRuleIds:

`$ruleIds = $quote->getAppliedRuleIds();`

Comment: $quote->getAppliedRuleIds(); not working

Comment: If you check the 'sales_flat_quote' table in your database is the column 'applied_rule_ids' filled for the quote you check?

Comment: yes field(applied_rule_ids) is exist in sales_flat_quote table but i can't get rules ids by using $quote->getAppliedRuleIds();

Comment: Can you post the complete code that you use?

Comment: I m using your code $quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();$ruleIds = $quote->getAppliedRuleIds();echo $ruleIds;exit; in Flatrate.php(shipping/Model/Carrier) page.

Comment: How to get rule label?

Answer (score 1):

As also asked and answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123793/how-to-get-shopping-cart-discounts-in-magento/123799#123799):

**Get applied rule IDs separated by commas:**

```
$appliedRuleIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

**Convert to array:**

```
$appliedRuleIds = explode(',', $appliedRuleIds);
```

**Convert to object**

```
$rules =  Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('rule_id' , array('in' => $appliedRuleIds));
```

**Get rules:**

```
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        // do something with $rule

        // get rule name or label:
        echo $rule->name;

        // get discount amount:
        echo $rule->discount_amount;

        // inspect the rule yourself:        
        var_dump($rule);
    }
```