# How to get Shopping Cart Discounts in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, discount, promotions, totals

Having multiple promotions (or discounts) applied for shopping carts, **how to get such promotions** so I can display them in view?

Update:
I want to get each. NOT the total. This is so I can display the labels of each promotions/discounts for the cart. Such as:

```
Sub Total: 100.00
Discounts:
   First Purchase: -10 (10%),
   Employee Discount: 5 (5%)
Shipping Fee: 20.00
Grand Total: 105
```

Comment: do u want the total discount amount or the shopping cart rules applied ?

Comment: I want to get to shopping cart rules applied as list not the totals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$appliedRuleIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

This will give you the ids of the rules applied to the quote separated by comma.
you can turn them into an array like this:

```
$appliedRuleIds = explode(',', $appliedRuleIds);
```

if you want to get the rules applied as objects you can do this:

```
$rules =  Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('rule_id' , array('in' => $appliedRuleIds));

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    //do something with $rule
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm now trying this out. I'll let you if this works.

Comment: This works. I'm getting the IDs of the applied rules. Now how do I get the name/label of the rule? Dumping the $rule returns too much data and causes the page to hang.

Comment: Got it! To get the rule label or name: $rule->name